# Asignar valores unsigned a los valores de una columna python

Tags: python

Tengo un dataframe 'a' donde tengo una columna con valores string (CAP). Quiero generar una nueva columna (id) que asigne un valor unsigned int 32 a cada valor único de la columna string con Python.

| CAP | id |
| --- | --- |
| Barcelona | 1 |
| Madrid | 2 |
| Valencia | 3 |
| Sevilla | 4 |
| Sevilla | 4 |
| Barcelona | 1 |

He intentado crear un bucle for que detecte la longitud de la columna CAP y me añada una columna en el dataframe con los valores de un np.arange, pero me da error.

¿Existe alguna manera de convertir un string a un int?
¿O existe alguna manera rápida y sencilla de asignar valores numéricos a strings?

En primer lugar, seleccione los valores únicos de la columna CAP y obtuve los 381 valores. Convertí esa columna en un dataframe y luego intenté lo siguiente:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
  a.insert(2, 'CAP_id', [np.arange(381, dtype='uint32')])
```

Me da error porque la columna es string y también ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (381)

Soy muy novata en Python, así que seguramente estoy haciendo muchas cosas mal, pero no logro arreglar esto.

¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿puedes mostrarnos un poco del código que has intentado? Haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber cómo formular una buena pregunta, ¡aún puedes editarla para que sea más útil para ti y el resto!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas ya tiene mecanismos para hacer justo lo que buscas. Una columna con valores de tipo string en los que cada posible valor representa un "caso" diferente y en el que se repiten a menudo los "casos" es lo que Pandas llama una columna de tipo "Categoría".

Puedes convertir la columna "CAP" de tu ejemplo a una columna de tipo de "categoría". Esto por sí solo ya es recomendable al hacer que esa columna automáticamente pase a ocupar menos memoria y sea más rápida y eficiente en su manejo (aunque al mostrar el dataframe se seguirá viendo exactamente igual):

```
df.CAP = df.CAP.astype("category")
```

```html
         CAP
0  Barcelona
1     Madrid
2   Valencia
3    Sevilla
4    Sevilla
5  Barcelona
```

Pero además, una vez la tienes del tipo "categoría", puedes hacer más cosas con ella, como por ejemplo acceder a su "código" que no es otra cosa que el identificador numérico único que estabas buscando. Así que:

```py
df["id"] = df.CAP.cat.codes
```

y este sería el resultado:

```html
         CAP  id
0  Barcelona   0
1     Madrid   1
2   Valencia   3
3    Sevilla   2
4    Sevilla   2
5  Barcelona   0
```

**Nota**: si te molesta que el id empiece en 0 en vez de 1, puedes sumarle 1, es decir: `df["id"] = df.CAP.cat.codes + 1`

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias! Ya veo que era más sencillo de lo que yo me estaba planteando. He aprendido mucho con tu respuesta, gracias.